# ndarray as column in Pandas dataframe stored as object. How to convert to numpy ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have stored ndarrays in a column of a Pandas dataframe. 
Now, I need to get the max of the column-wise sum of the ndarray. However, in Pandas, the ndarray is stored as an object ('O'). Therefore, I cannot do numpy operations.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
def get_max_column_of_matrix(column):
    return np.max(column.sum(0))

def apply_max_column_of_matrix(df):
    return df.assign(
        max_sum=df.apply(lambda d: get_max_column_of_matrix(d['matrix']), axis=1)
    )
```

This is my example dataframe:

```
    matrix
0   "[[4 2 3]
 [1 4 3]
 [6 3 8]]"
1   "[[3 3 6]
 [2 7 6]
 [2 1 4]]"
2   "[[6 9 4]
 [8 3 6]
 [4 7 8]]"
```

I expect this result:

```
    max_sum
0   14
1   16
2   19
```

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'sum'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: Those elements look like `str(an_array)`.  Did you load this from a `csv`?  If so look at that file.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like in example below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()

df["A"] = [np.random.rand(3,3) for i in range(5)]
df.apply(lambda x: x["A"].sum(0), axis=1)
```

looks like your "matrix" column is string, from where are you loading your data?

try to check type of the column like below

`df["matrix"].apply(lambda x: type(x))`

Comment: Your sample data are different like OP, so cannot be used here

Comment: Yes, it also worked for me haha. But apparently, my real dataframe was different. I found a solution though with: apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(
            x.replace('\n','')
                .replace('[','')
                .replace(']','')
                .replace('  ',' '), sep=' ')),

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but much better is not save 2d numpy array to file, because really complicated parsing:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
import numpy as np

a = """[[4 2 3]
[1 4 3]
[6 3 8]]"""
df = pd.DataFrame({'matrix':[a,a]})

f = lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(x.replace('\n',' ').replace(' ', ',')))
df['matrix']  = df['matrix'].apply(f)
print (df)
                              matrix
0  [[4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3], [6, 3, 8]]
1  [[4, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3], [6, 3, 8]]

def get_max_column_of_matrix(column):
    return np.max(column.sum(0))

max_sum=df.apply(lambda d: get_max_column_of_matrix(d['matrix']), axis=1)
print (max_sum)
0    14
1    14
dtype: int64
```